# Assertion, is null or is an instance of specific Class

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, assertions, hamcrest

simple I thought

```
 Assert.assertThat(
                iterator.next(),
                Matchers.either(Matchers.nullValue()).or(
                        Matchers.instanceOf(Double.class)));
```

So I'd like to ensre next() returns one of two, NULL or instance of a Double.
Sth like

```
Assert.assertTrue(next == null || next instanceof Double);
```

Test run (`assertThat`) outcomes in...

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V
at org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher.matchesSafely(CombinableMatcher.java:17)
at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.matches(TypeSafeDiagnosingMatcher.java:55)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:772)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:738
```

Why? And how to fix?

**EDIT**

You were right, there was a collision with hamcrest lib comming from Mockito. I have it fixed.
Ther's no error but the assertion fails strangely, take a look:

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: 
 Expected: (null or an instance of java.lang.Double)
 got: null
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:780)
at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:738)
```

Null was expected, got null and a test is failing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JMock- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070514/jmock-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matcher-describemismatch)

Answer (score 2):

The `NoSuchMethodError` indicates an issue concerning the difference between the compile-time and runtime environment. A typical cause would be that you have a different version of a JAR at runtime. Maybe you have two Hamcrest JARs, but one takes precedence. Carefully check the compile-time and runtime classpaths.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you have multiple dependencies of Hamcrest that are in conflict. Check your build path / maven dependencies.

If you execute the search on `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch` you will get the following list of entries for the exact same problem:

[Did you search before posting this question?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:%20org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch)

The first result looks right to me:

[First search result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12070514/jmock-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-hamcrest-matcher-describemismatch)